# How could to improve performance select rows in a data frame using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to select rows from df2 which contains the same values of a few columns in another data.frame.

Firstly I generate some data to show my question.

```
set.seed(1)

df1 <- expand.grid(list(A = 1:30, B = 1:30, D = 1:30))
df1$value <- runif(nrow(df1))

df2 <- expand.grid(list(A = 1:30, B = 1:30, C = 1:30, D = 1:30))
df2$value <- runif(nrow(df2))
```

Then I calculate the maximum values for column A in df1.

```
library(dplyr)

df1_opt <- tbl_df(df1) %>%
    group_by(A) %>%
    filter(value == max(value)) %>%
    arrange(A)
```

Now I need to select rows in df2 which have the same values of columns A, B, D in df1.

```
selectRow <- function(.data)
{
    pos <- df1_opt$A %in% .data$A[1]
    pos2 <- .data$B == df1_opt$B[pos] & 
        .data$D == df1_opt$D[pos]
    return(.data[pos2,])

}

system.time(df2_opt <- tbl_df(df2) %>%
    group_by(A, B, C) %>%
    do(selectRow(.)))
```

My codes take about 40 s in a virtual server. How could I improve the performance of my codes? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: In your toy example, I can get the same (but speedier) results for `df2_opt` if I don't `group_by`.  Is the grouping an important part of your real scenario?

Comment: Thanks, In my case, it is not necessary to use group_by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is just a semi-join:

```
library(dplyr)
tbl_df(df2) %>% 
  semi_join(df1_opt, by = c("A", "B", "D"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. semi_join is much faster than others.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility:

```
df2$E <- do.call(paste, c(df2[c("A", "B", "D")], sep="_"))
df1_opt$E <- do.call(paste, c(df1_opt[c("A", "B", "D")], sep="_"))
df2_opt <- df2%.%group_by(A,B,C)%.%filter(E%in%df1_opt$E)
```

hth

Comment: And if you didn't want to make new variables, you could do the pasting inside `filter`: `filter(paste(A,B,D, sep = ".") %in% paste(df1_opt$A, df1_opt$B, df1_opt$D, sep = "."))`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. it is much faster now.